# "this" inside of object in coffee script class

Tags: coffeescript

Inside my class I have object (just to put all related functions for convenience) so then I call them "this" point to the current object.

For example:

```
class Test
    constructor: ->
        @vir = ""

    helpers:
        func1: ->
            @vir = "a" (I can't do it because this point to object "func1")
        func2: ->
```

Actually, I can pass my root object (or that global variable) as parameter but I want to know the coffee script way, maybe there is another way as "=>" for events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript classes don't quite work that way. When you say things like:

```
class C
    helpers:
        f: -> console.log(@)
```

the `helpers` will just be an object attached to `C`'s prototype. There won't be any special attachment to C so this:

```
c = new C
c.helpers.f()
```

is the same as:

```
c = new C
h = c.helpers
h.f()
```

and both will dump `helpers` itself in the console.

You can't use `=>` to help anything here because, again, `helpers` is just an object with no special connection to `C`. So if you try this:

```
class C
    helpers:
        f: => console.log(@)
c = new C
c.helpers.f()
```

you'll get `C` itself in the console. This happens because `f` here is just a function inside an object that's attached to `C`'s prototype, `f` isn't really a method at all.

There are a few ways around this.

1. Get rid of `helpers` completely and use `=>`:

   ```
   class Test
       constructor: -> @vir = ""
       func1: => @vir = "a"
   t = new Test
   f = t.func1
   f() # @ is what you expect it to be
   ```
2. Bind all the functions inside `helpers` when you create a new instance:

   ```
   class Test
       constructor: ->
           @vir = ""
           helpers = { }
           helpers[name] = f.bind(@) for name, f of @helpers
           @helpers = helpers # Be careful not to mess up the prototype
       helpers:
           func1: -> @vir = "a"
   t = new Test
   f = t.helpers.func1
   f()
   ```
3. Bind the functions when you give them to your event handling system:

   ```
   class Test
       constructor: -> @vir = ""
       helpers:
           func1: -> @vir = "a"
   t = new Test
   whatever.on('some-event', t.helpers.func1.bind(t))
   ```
4. Tell the event handling system what `@` should be. Some event systems let you specify what `this` to use when calling event handlers, I don't know what's managing your events so this may or may not be applicable.

   ```
   class Test
       constructor: -> @vir = ""
       helpers:
           func1: -> @vir = "a"
   t = new Test
   whatever.on('some-event', t.helpers.func1, t) # Assuming your event system understands a "context" argument
   ```

There are certainly other ways around this but I think the above are the most common approaches.